# I am getting this error: could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory

Tags: java, maven

I am getting the following error in my project:

> [SEVERE] faces: Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarr a Injection SPI?
>
> [SEVERE] faces: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. Attempting to find backup.
>
> [WARNING] /eloqua-java-connector: unavailable java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.

pom.xml

```xml
<properties>
    <cxf.version>3.0.0</cxf.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jetty.version>9.2.1.v20140609</jetty.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>eloqua-service</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
    <display-name>cxf</display-name>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS</param-name>
    <param-value>home.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
   <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>InvokeSiebel Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.i3l.eloqua.server.InvokeSiebelServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/sessionexpired.jsf</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

and put

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

It will solve the problem,

You can see my uploaded full configured JSF2.2 frontend application
[JSF2 web app](https://github.com/armdev/jsf-frontend/blob/master/pom.xml)

Comment: i have made the changes but still getting same error. Iam using jetty server not glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the following changes into your web.xml config file:

'context-param' {
'param-name' ('com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration')
'param-value' ('true')
}